# Getinfo only returns the first cover inserted

Tags: javascript, openlayers, wms, getfeatureinfo

I'm using GetInfo to view the cover information and my problem using this command is:
The information displayed is not from the cover seen on the map, but from the first cover inserted in the code. I always see information from the cover Layer_21_11_19 even if I'm seeing and clicking on the cover Layer_12_12_19.

**Please, does anyone know how to show the information only on the cover I'm seeing and clicking?**

```js
map.on('click', function getInfo(e){
 if(e.name !== 'Click'){
  e.name = "Click";
  map.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
   const projection = map.getView().getProjection().getCode()
   const isGlobal = map.getView().getProjection().isGlobal()
   const viewResolution = view.getResolution();
   const wmsSource = new ol.source.ImageWMS({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/WORK/wms',
     params: {'LAYERS': [
      'Layer_21_11_19',
      'Layer_23_11_19',
      'Layer_12_12_19'
     ]}
   });
   url = wmsSource.getFeatureInfoUrl(
    evt.coordinate,
    viewResolution,
    'EPSG:4326',
    {'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/html','FEATURE_COUNT': 1}
   );
 }
})
```

Comment: getFeatureInfoUrl returns the url needed to search a 100px bbox around the coordinate at the supplied resolution.  For more precision try reducing the resolution.

Comment: Mike, thanks for the suggestion. I tried doing it like this, but all the points of the covers are located in the same study area, so the problem remains the same.